# jQuery DOM Traversal with closest()

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the row below:

[image]

When the span field in the second td is clicked I want to change the text in the td.enPublish for the row.

What I have now is

```
 $('span#publish_field').click (function() {
    title = this.title;  // this is a raw DOM span node, so we can go directly after the title attribute.
    $(this).closest("tr").$('td.enPublished').text('steve');
    $.post("set_publish.php", { "product_id" : title }, function(echoed_data) { 
            alert (echoed_data);
        });
```

The third line is supposed to get at that field, but it doesn't.   Does anyone see the problem?

The title attribute holds a product_id value for that row and is used in the ajax call to set a field in the database.  I thought I could also update the field here in the HTML so the user wouldn't have to refresh the page to see it.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$` to `find`

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('td.enPublished').text('steve');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `find()`

try this

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('td.enPublished').text('steve');
```